# Why combining two unbuffers give this error?

Tags: buffer

I am reading this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14124550/54964) and run test code

```
unbuffer xxd -ps /usr/bin/telnet | unbuffer -p less
```

but get `Missing filename ("less --help" for help)`.

Why combining two unbuffers give this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, `unbuffer` does not read from `stdin`. To use `unbuffer` in a pipeline, use the `-p` flag.  Example:

```
process1 | unbuffer -p process2 | process3
```

That is the way to do it. But you used `unbuffer` at the last process, which doesn’t make sense and doesn’t work (obviously). So your command should look:

```
unbuffer xxd -ps /usr/bin/telnet | less
```

**Explanation:** `unbuffer`  disables  the *output buffering* that occurs when program output is *redirected* from non-interactive programs. **But** `less` is **not redirecting.**

*Source of all this text: manpage of unbuffer.*